# How to measure client side page load time?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-management, load-testing

I need to measure response time for a website.

1. Response time to open a page of a web site: 
   I mean the loading time, some way to see the difference in time before and after open a website page.

   > But this way, measuring the client loading time, will depend on the client used client.  What is the best way to measure that?

   ```
   long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

   driver.get("http://zyxware.com");
   new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("Calculate")));

   long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   long totalTime = endTime - startTime;

   System.out.println("Total Page Load Time: " + totalTime + "milliseconds");
   ```

or this?

```
driver.get("url");
        WebElement ele = $(By.tagName("body"));
        // get the  page load time
        Long loadtime = (Long)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
            "return performance.timing.loadEventEnd - performance.timing.navigationStart;");        
        System.out.println(loadtime);
```

and last way the following:

```
StopWatch pageLoad = new StopWatch();
            pageLoad.start();
            //Open your web app (In my case, I opened facebook)
            driver.get("url");
            // Wait for the required any element (I am waiting for Login button in fb)
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.tagName("body")));

            pageLoad.stop();
            //Get the time
            long pageLoadTime_ms = pageLoad.getTime();
            long pageLoadTime_Seconds = pageLoadTime_ms / 1000;
            System.out.println("Total Page Load Time: " + pageLoadTime_ms + " milliseconds");
```

2. if I have a search button for the same website, if I need to measure the search time, how to do it? is it as same as the above way?

Comment: You tagged this with load-testing but your question seems to be about page load time, which is something else.

Comment: I recommend to measure these kinda KPIs at API level specially search response time. I should say, such measures even at API level are not very accurate since it is affected by different factors e.g. Network.

Comment: What do you mean by `search time`?  Does that include the time to render the search results page?

Comment: @user246, yes how it take to load the search result in the same website.

Comment: @masoodghz, did you mean at development phase?

Comment: @user246
Please, see the edited question. I have three ways which is the best one?

Comment: @masoodghz
Please, see the edited question. I have three ways which is the best one?

Comment: Are you programming in JAVA or C#?

Comment: Tried to rescue the question a bit and make it more applicable to others.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is the wrong tool for measuring page load times.  Selenium can't actually block until the page finishes loading, so it has to poll the browser.  Your load time precision is constrained by the poll interval.

The most accurate tools for measuring page load times are browser extensions like [YSlow](http://yslow.org/), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), and the [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

Comment: I need this check to be automated, can I do it with these extensions?

Comment: Please, see the edited question. I have three ways which is the best one?

Comment: Measure all three approaches, then measure the actual load time using the extensions I described above, and pick the approach that is the most accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Try using XSLT reports this report will give you page loading time and in your script set wait.until logic below is the sample for script and the code for XSLT report. check index.html report you will page loading time. And set Web driver wait time to high like 5 minutes see the example. Hope this will help.

//Wait for maximum 5 minutes if needed 
      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300);

script:

```
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='displayname']")));
```

XSLT code Add this in xml:

```
        <xslt in="${ng.result}/testng-results.xml" style="src/com/SatoriMainProject/xslt/testng-results.xsl"
              out="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output/index.html" classpathref="test.c" processor="SaxonLiaison">
            <param name="testNgXslt.outputDir" expression="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output/"/>
            <param name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" expression="true"/>
        </xslt>
    </target>
```